# cPanel HTML can't open site: 403 Forbidden

Tags: html, cpanel, namecheap

I just purchased cPanel web hosting with Namecheap for a URL website I have:

[image]

Then after reading some brief tutorials, I logged into cPanel, created a basic index.html to test, put it in the public_html folder, and set all the permissions to what should work:

[image]

However when I go to my IP address, http://19X.XX.XXX.XXX I see this:

[image]

Nevermind getting anything to show up on my [www.websitename.com](http://www.websitename.com) yet (how will I do that?).

I am new to cPanel and setting up websites in general.

Answer (score 0):

once you create the `public_html` folder create a file called `index.html` and one called `.htaccess` within the `.htaccess` file you'll need to set up the following;

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Once these are created your file tree won't be visible to the public and you'll need to create both `forbidden.html` and `notfound.html` within the main public html file. I'd also recommend just creating a page called `test.html` and adding the following:

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>This is a test page.</h2>
```

That way you should be able to navigate to `mydomain.com/test.html` and see the output of the html page. Add a comment if you have any further questions.